# How to access updated class variable from within the class?

Tags: python, class, properties

Take this class:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self._a = "Thisa"
        self.b = "Thisb"
        self.ab = self.a + self.b

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a
    
    @a.setter
    def a(self, value):
        self._a = value
```

Test it from Thonny:

```
> from test import *

> boo = test()

> print(boo.a)
Thisa

> print(boo.b)
Thisb

> print(boo.ab)
ThisaThisb

> boo.a = "baa"

> print(boo.ab)
ThisaThisb
```

How do you get: "baaThisb" ?

Comment: you calculate the value in the init method and never change it for .ab   you need to have something done in the setter method for a to update the ab value.

Comment: Hint: how did you make it so that `boo.a` gives the correct result after `boo._a` actually changes? What if you try **using the same technique** to make `boo.ab` give the correct result after the underlying data changes? Also, try to think carefully about the logic. Do you at least **understand** the cause of the problem? (Hint: **when** does the code `self.ab = self.a + self.b` happen?)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Always knew I don't understand things and can't think carefully but here I couldn't figure out in what way.

Answer (score 1):

The `a` property doesn't do anything and is redundant.  Just assign to `a` or `b` directly.  `ab` should be the calculated property:

```py
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 'Thisa'
        self.b = 'Thisb'

    @property
    def ab(self):
        return self.a + self.b

boo = Test()
print(f'{boo.a=}')
print(f'{boo.b=}')
print(f'{boo.ab=}')
boo.a = 'baa'
print(f'{boo.ab=}')
boo.b = 'blah'
print(f'{boo.ab=}')
```

Output:

```
boo.a='Thisa'
boo.b='Thisb'
boo.ab='ThisaThisb'
boo.ab='baaThisb'
boo.ab='baablah'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `self.ab` is only being set in the constructor. You probably want something along these lines:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self._a = "Thisa"
        self._b = "Thisb"

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a

    @property
    def b(self):
        return self._b
    
    @a.setter
    def a(self, value):
        self._a = value

    @b.setter
    def b(self, value):
        self._b = value

    @property
    def ab(self):
        return self._a + self._b
```